# How to control the size of the downloaded map area for each zoom level in OSMDroid?

Tags: download, maps, size, offline, osmdroid

I'm using offline maps downloaded from OpenStreetMaps on my Android application.

When I move the map some tiles do not appears.

I whould like to choose the area of n kilometers by m kilometers or something else.

Comment: How are you downloading the tiles?  How are you storeing the tiles?  How are you displaying the tiles?

Comment: To use maps offline:mMapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
mMapView.setUseDataConnection(false);

Comment: The storage is made automatically by OSMDroid library. I don't know exactly how it works. The tiles are show in a MapView from OSMDroid library.

Answer (score 0):

You are curently just getting the tiles osmdroid has in it's cache.  It caches tiles automaticaly as it downloads the.  There is no easy way of getting tiles into the cache without first trying to display them with online enabled.

If you realy want offline support you have to prepare a file with the tiles you need and get it into the sdcard/osmdroid/ direcrctory.  The simplest method of creating the file is to use a tool like [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/)  I would recomend the GEMF format over .zip it just works far better procedure is the same just copy the file and it is found automaticaly.